# Displaying texts one by one in same UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel in my app which display chat messages. These chat messages are hardcoded as an array of strings. What i need is to display these messages one by one on a UILabel but i need to have a certain 2 second delay between switching messages as user need to read each message.

What i have implemented is the following code:

```
for chatText in chatDialogue{


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    chatLabel.text=chatText as? String
                })
                println(chatText)
                NSThread .sleepForTimeInterval(2)
            }
```

here we have an array of chatDialogues

```
["Hello","How are you?","Can you say DIAS","Wait Please"]
```

Now i need these to be displayed on the same label but with a say delay between changing messages.

The above implementation when executed showed only the last message on the loop.

Comment: Wouldn't `NSThread .sleepForTimeInterval(2)` block main thread therefore UI can't be refreshed so you can't see the changes to label? Maybe calling `layoutIfNeeded` after setting text would help. No idea though, just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `NSTimer` which fires every 2 seconds and stops when reaching the last text:

```
// instance variables
let chatDialoges = ["Hello","How are you?","Can you say DIAS","Wait Please"]
var textIndex = 0
var timer: NSTimer?

// ...

// somewhere where the timer should start
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//

func update() {
    self.textLabel++

    if self.textLabel == chatDialoges.count {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        return
    }

    chatLabel.text = chatDialoges[self.textIndex]
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! I was looking for a much simpler solution.